# Zapier JavaScript: Extract text array and Return that array

Tags: javascript, zapier

Please excuse me if this question is silly .. My code is now like:

```
var arr_original = data.split(',');
var arr_new = [0, 0, ""];

for (var i = 0; i < arr_original.length; i++) {
  if (arr_original[i] === "Apple") {
    arr_new[1] = 1;
  } else if (arr_original[i] === “Orange”） {
    arr_new[2] = 1;
  } else {
    arr_new[3] = arr_arr_original[i];
  }
}

output = [{Is_Applie: arr_new[1], Is_Orange: array_new[2], 
Is_Something_Else: array_new[3]}];
```

Where is the error??

Answer (score 0):

If your string (called "data") is "check item 1, check item 2, check item 3" then you can do this:

```
const numbers = data.split(',').map(el => el[el.length -1]);
```

This splits up your string by using comma as a delimiter, then for each of those split up sections, it gets the last character of that section (the number). This will only work if the number is positive and < 10 by the way, thus it would return:

```
[1, 2, 3]
```